# Stop running jobs in parallel Gitlab CI

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, jobs

Is there any way to stop jobs running in parallel in gitlab CI?
My gitlab-ci.yml file is:

```
image: google/cloud-sdk:slim

stages: 
  - deploy

before_script:
  - echo $ENVIRONMENT
  - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file $GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE
  - gcloud config set project $GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID

deploy_website:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - sed -i -e 's/https:\/\/us-central1-ahinko-website.cloudfunctions.net\/send_contact'/$GOOGLE_CLOUD_FUNCTION_EMAIL_URL'/g' src/client-side/js/custom-script.js
    - gsutil -m rm $GOOGLE_CLOUD_BUCKET/**
    - gsutil -m cp -R src/client-side/* $GOOGLE_CLOUD_BUCKET
  environment:
    name: $ENVIRONMENT

deploy_cloud_function: 
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - gcloud functions deploy send_contact --entry-point=send_contact_form --ingress-settings=all --runtime=python37 --source=src/server-side/cf-send-email/ --trigger-http
  when: on_success
  environment:
    name: $ENVIRONMENT
```

Both runs in parallel, and i don't want in this way..
[image: jobs running in parallel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use stages: they will be executed in the order defined in the `stages` declaration.

```
image: google/cloud-sdk:slim

stages: 
  - deploy
  - cloud

before_script:
  - echo $ENVIRONMENT
  - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file $GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE
  - gcloud config set project $GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID

deploy_website:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - sed -i -e 's/https:\/\/us-central1-ahinko-website.cloudfunctions.net\/send_contact'/$GOOGLE_CLOUD_FUNCTION_EMAIL_URL'/g' src/client-side/js/custom-script.js
    - gsutil -m rm $GOOGLE_CLOUD_BUCKET/**
    - gsutil -m cp -R src/client-side/* $GOOGLE_CLOUD_BUCKET
  environment:
    name: $ENVIRONMENT

deploy_cloud_function: 
  stage: cloud
  script:
    - gcloud functions deploy send_contact --entry-point=send_contact_form --ingress-settings=all --runtime=python37 --source=src/server-side/cf-send-email/ --trigger-http
  when: on_success
  environment:
    name: $ENVIRONMENT
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it was the solution!